# What steps have to be taken to marry?

Tags: nikah

As a new convert to Islam, what steps have to be taken to marry under Islam?

I am presently being divorced from my wife at the moment but there is another woman I would like to marry. She is a mature woman with family who have done everything within their power of guardianship to stop us from getting married.

Can she be married with out there permission as long as we have a wali and witnesses at the nikah. Also would I then become her main guardian?  Or should we wait till my divorce is completed?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to make yourself familiar with our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Just to make something clear wali (in Arabic) means guardian. So a wali is the guardian of a woman. And basically as long as a woman isn't married or has no husband her father or in his absence a male relative would be the wali- Once she is married her husband is her wali.

Comment: I think their might be questions that you asked answered on the site not in all one question so try look for them and they might help you.

Answer (score 1):

NewMuslims.com has sections entitled *Marriage Advice* parts [1](https://www.newmuslims.com/lessons/156/) and [2](https://www.newmuslims.com/lessons/157/).  Importantly, it's ill-advised to rush into marriage.

> For a new Muslim, this author would advise to wait at least a year, preferably more, before thinking about getting married.  Marriage is a big decision and one must allow oneself sufficient time to grow before making such a life-changing decision.

It's particularly dangerous for converts: they rush into marriage, wind up getting divorced, then leave Islam.

NewMuslims.com has a page [The Nuts & Bolts of an Islamic Marriage](https://www.newmuslims.com/lessons/158/).  Relevant here is:

> Marriage Contract
>
> In Islam, the marriage is a contract between the two parties. The four
>   basic conditions for the marriage contract to be valid are:
>
> 1. Consent of the woman’s walee (marriage guardian)
> 2. Agreement of the woman
> 3. Two male, Muslim witnesses
> 4. The offer to marry and it’s acceptance

There are exceptions to the consent of the wali (e.g., if she's been married before, and depending on which fiqh is involved); see [If a girl marries her boyfriend without her parents' consent, is their marriage accepted by Allah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31221/17163)

However, one should not take the wali's lack of consent lightly: they will still exist even if you get married, and it's unpleasant for a woman to be torn between her family and husband.  This will likely put a strain on your marriage.

> Also would I then become her main guardian?

Basically, yes; see [What role does the wali (guardian) play after a woman is married?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37825/17163)

> Or should we wait till my divorce is completed?

Yes, it's just common sense.  It gets messy if you're married to one woman Islamically and another woman legally.  And it would be unpleasant for you're prospective wife to be dragged into this mess.